# How do I set vim as the default editor when I sudo?

Tags: vim, sudo, vi

I'm working on a CentOS 5.9 machine, and I simply want to type

> sudo vi somefile

and have my trusty vim with syntax highlighting, etc. This seems simple enough, but after many attempts, it's still not working.

```
root@localhost> which vi
alias vi='vim'
        /usr/bin/vim
root@localhost> sudo which vi
/bin/vi
root@localhost> sudo -i which vi
/bin/vi
root@localhost> sudo -E which vi
/bin/vi
```

I logged in as root to ensure that by default `vi somefile` invoked vim. It did. I also tried to preserve the environment with -E and run the login scripts with -i. That did not work. In both my .profile and /etc/environment, I export the EDITOR as vim, and set vi as an alias to vim.

I also commented out a env_reset line in /etc/sudoers.

What else should I try? I didn't think replacing vi with vim would be so difficult, and I really like to understand what is going on here.

Answer (score 11):

That's what the command `sudoedit` is for. It creates a temporary copy that is edited in the users environment. It consults `SUDO_EDITOR`, `VISUAL` and the variable `EDITOR` to find a suitable binary. After the edit the copy overwrites the original file.

Answer (score 5):

In case you always want to use `vim` instead of `vi`, you can just

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/vim /usr/local/bin/vi
```

(This assumes you have `/usr/local/bin` *before* `/bin` in your `PATH`.)

Granted, it's a (system-local) hack, but quite simple and effective.

Comment: Bad practice to create symlinks on the fly. Better to either create a `~/bin/` directory and create a symlink in there and add `~/bin/` to `PATH` or to use the `EDITOR` variable and pass it along when `sudo`ing by editing the sudoers file.

Comment: @mtahmed The `~/bin/` and `PATH` doesn't help much when the problem is around cross-user launches. I also have less reservations about symlinks (especially in `.../local/...` dirs), but YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the reason for the observed behavior may be found in the PATH variable. It is possible that as a regular logged-in user the segment `/usr/bin` comes before `/bin`, while when sudoing as *root*, the segment `/bin` comes before `/usr/bin`.

If so, the difference can be traced to either one or both of the following origins. If the value of PATH is different when using *sudo*, this points to the *secure_path* configuration parameter, typically set in `/etc/sudoers` or one of the `/etc/sudoers.d/*` files. However, if the value of PATH is different when logged-in as *root* (whether a first-level login or with *sudo*'s `-i`/`--login` switch), this points to a startup file such as `/etc/{profile,profile.d/*}` and `/etc/{bashrc,bash_*}`.

I don't have a CentOS 5 installation handy, but my Alma 8 server gives the following:

```bash
## As a regular logged-in user
$ echo $PATH
/home/me/.local/bin:/home/me/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin

## Sudoing as root (notice the reverse order)
$ sudo bash -c 'echo $PATH'           
/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

## Sudoing as myself (same value)
$ sudo -u me bash -c 'echo $PATH'
/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

## Indeed...
$ sudo grep secure_path /etc/sudoers
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

You might also give a quick glance at *sudo*'s *env_keep* parameter and add VISUAL and EDITOR to the list of kept variables if not already there, but since you mentioned that *env_reset* was turned off, it probably won't change much.

Comment: Oh... Ha, ha! Just saw the date that the original question was posted at. I'll nonetheless leave my reply --- now that it's all written — in case someone else runs into the same question.